# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calcOnDemand' of null

Tags: spreadjs

[image]

I'm getting this error when I click outside the spreadsheet, after creating a new blank file from the File tab

What is the problem in this?

Comment: Please post code and not pictures of code (or even only error messages) ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using SpreadJS.
It is difficult to know exactly what is going on based on your description.  Do you have a simple code that you can share that replicates the issue.

Just in case, you can set the calcOnDemand option using spread.options.calcOnDemand = false;  where spread is the name of your spreadJS instance.
[Grapecity SpreadJS Team](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've actually hurred up with creating this ticket and I wrote the very poor explanation. I've just added a more detailed description in spreadJS forum.